# MariaDB Inner join is slow

Tags: execution-plan, performance, mariadb-10.3, performance-tuning

Here is my SQL (with explain):

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT * FROM
GBI gbi
INNER JOIN VF_KRED kred ON
    gbi.vendor = kred.vendor;
```

Giving below the outcome:

[image]

Now, the `select` SQL takes ~10 seconds to produce the outcome.

Below are the indexes on tables:

- VF_KRED table:

[image]

- GBI table:

[image]

Any clues?

Comment: Experiencing the same.
MySQL needs less than a second, MariaDB runs 13 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Our solution: Set the variable `optimizer_search_depth` to zero.
The same query now needs 0.3 instead of 13 seconds.

To test it, call before your statement:

```sql
set SESSION optimizer_search_depth=0;
```

To make it permanent put it in the my.conf file and restart the db.

Comment: Helpful info: "When it is set to 0, the optimizer tries to pick a reasonable search depth. Currently, it does this by setting the search depth to the number of tables used in the query, up to a maximum value of 7." - [documentation for `optimizer_search_depth`](https://mariadb.com/docs/server/ref/mdb/system-variables/optimizer_search_depth/)

Comment: @mbomb007 They changed to that better behavior in the 4 years since my response.